# Access Report: Sum up the two formula text boxes in a new text box

Tags: ms-access, formula

I have a report in Access that sums up some fields in two text boxes. Now, I need to sum up the two formula text boxes on a new text box and

=Sum("FormulatxtBoxNameA]*3")+Sum("[FormulatxtBoxNameB]*1")

does not work. I get "Error". I have tried several ways of typing this formula and I just cannot gain any ground. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why `Sum()`? Would this not work? `= ([FormulatxtBoxNameA] * 3) + [FormulatxtBoxNameB]`

Comment: @PaulFrancis Excel users ;-)